# Flutter: how to save state between widget rebuilds

Tags: flutter

I am building a chat application. In this a user can select a chat and reply to it, and all replies are attached to the same chat (like a mail group).

So, I have Chat1>Chat2>Chat3>(reply being typed) - and while the user is typing, another reply comes in, so I need to show Chat1>Chat2>Chat3>ChatNew>(reply being typed).

For my design, I am saving the (reply being typed) using Riverpod in the deactivate (tried dispose too) and retrieving this in the initState, and threading things in order.

The issue is that the initState gets called before the deactivate/dispose save the reply. I need to use the `Future((){})` to save state to Riverpod (and I must continue to use Riverpod as I need the Family feature).

How do I ensure that the save happens before the build, or is this just not possible? Maybe the deactivate/dispose happen lazily, and the new widget gets built first for performance?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I presumed, it cannot be done with my approach.

I changed to code to 'watch' for the state in the build and that was what worked - seems there is no way to 'transfer' state between widgets using the deactivate/dispose methods.